# Strings stored in a wrong charset on database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with varchar elements stored in a database.
In order to be printed in the correct way they have been stored in a strange collapse that i can not understand, see this example:
[Data Stored incorrectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL37G.png)

You can notice that €™ in the strings. It should be an "è". Same things happen for ' and for "à". How can i change the character set of the database in order to display properly the varchar elements?
Currently settings are:

Storage engine: MyISAM

Collation: latin1_swedish_ci

Thank you very much. I really need help. I tried a lot of collations but nothing seems to work.

Comment: How are you inserting your records? Are you using a framework? Is this pure PDO? Could you provide more info please? If you can provide code, that can also help.

Comment: They have been stored in a strange collation*

Comment: Hi Ravi. The records had been insert directly into the database from other users. They did not used a framework, just plain php and html.

Comment: Are you using MySQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359827/cant-get-the-right-characters-to-display-from-the-database?rq=1

Comment: Yes I am using MySQL

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, collation is for ordering and comparison, not recording.

You might be looking for encoding instead as it is responsible for the characters itself.

I believe that your issue is that you have the wrong encoding. Before you you set it to UTF8, please change your collation to utf8_unicode_ci.

Please attempt to run this:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

That should resolve your issue for new records. The old ones will remain untouched.

Comment: @Alexandru Did my answer help you solve your question? If so, please do not hesitate to mark this as your best answer.